# Parsing a Pandas DataFrame to nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame on the following format

```
 Path    |    Val 
 A/B           1
 A/C           3 
A/D/E          5
 A/E           7
 F/G           9
 ...          ...
```

And I want to transform this into a nested dictionary where they level of keys will be the Path variable separated by "/".

The expected output would be

```
 d =  {'A' : 
            {'B' : 1, 'C' : 3} , 
             'D' : 
                  {'E' : 5}, 
             'E' : 7},
       'F' : 
            {'G' : 9}
      }
```

What would be an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

##### Seperating the Column Path

```
df[['main_path','Subpath1','Subpath2']]=df["Path"].str.split("/",expand=True)
```

[image]

##### Creating new dataframe with subpath1 group

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Subpath1']).agg({'Val': list, 'main_path': 'first'}).reset_index()
```

[image]

##### Creating another dataframe with subpath2 group

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Subpath2']).agg({'Val': list, 'Subpath1': 'first'})
```

[image]

##### Create dict for subpath1

```
df2 = df2.groupby(['Subpath1']).agg(dict).reset_index()
```

[image]

##### Merging the Dict to df1

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Subpath1'], how='left')
```

[image]

##### Replace NaN value from Val_y with Val_x value

```
df3['Val'] = df3['Val_y'].fillna(df3['Val_x'])
```

[image]

##### Droping columns

```
df3 = df3.drop(['Val_x', 'Val_y'], axis=1)

# Setting subpath1 as index
df3 = df3.set_index('Subpath1')
```

[image]

##### Final dict

```
df4 = df3.groupby(['main_path']).agg(dict)
df4.to_json(orient='columns')
```

##### Output

```
{"Val":{"A":{"B":[1],"C":[3],"D":{"E":[5]},"E":[7]},"F":{"G":[9]}}}
```